# Why am I receiving a CrashLoopBackOff error for my Blazor app in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, blazor-server-side

I am trying to deploy a ASP.NET v6, Blazor-Server-Side App in a local Kubernetes environment using Minikube (hyperv driver). However, no matter what I try, I end up with a Status of `CrashLoopBackOff`. To top it off, my app isn't providing any logs. I will try to provides as many snippets of relevant files and kubectl outputs as possible.

Dockerfile (Basically the default Dockerfile as given by VS2022):

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["project.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./project.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project.dll"]
```

Helm Files: 
Chart.yml:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: project
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.6
appVersion: "0.2.0"

dependencies:
# - name: postgresql
#   version: "13.4.2"
#   repository: "@bitnami"
# - name: pgadmin4
#   version: "1.23.1"
#   repository: "@runix"
```

templates/deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: project-deployment
  labels:
    app: project-deployment
spec:
  # replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: project-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: project-deployment
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      containers:
      - name: project-pod
        image: registry/project/app:0.2.3
        # resources:
        #   requests:
        #     cpu: "100m"
        #     memory: "256Mi"
        #   limits:
        #     cpu: "500m"
        #     memory: "512Mi"
        # env:
        # - name: RedisConfig__UseAsBackplane
        #   value: "false"
        # - name: RedisConfig__Settings__Host
        #   value: "sigredis-master.default.svc.cluster.local"
        # - name: RedisConfig__Settings__Password
        #   value: "none"
        #   valueFrom:
        #     secretKeyRef:
        #       name: sigredis
        #       key: redis-password
        # - name: PodName
        #   valueFrom:
        #     fieldRef:
        #       fieldPath: metadata.name
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
```

templates/service.yml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name:  project-service
spec:
  selector:
    app:  project-deployment
  ports:
  - name: http
    port:  80
    targetPort:  80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

templates/ingress.yml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: project-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: project.local
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: project-service
              port:
                number: 80
```

Kubectl Outputs: 
`kubectl get all`:

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS       AGE
pod/project-deployment-5cfb9ccfbd-r7zgj   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (2m8s ago)   13m
pod/ubuntu-pod                          1/1     Running            0              13m

NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
service/project-service   LoadBalancer   10.99.32.145   <pending>     80:30883/TCP,443:31528/TCP   13m
service/kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP                      8d

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/project-deployment   0/1     1            0           13m

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/project-deployment-5cfb9ccfbd   1         1         0       13m
```

`kubectl describe pod/project-deployment-5cfb9ccfbd-r7zgj`:

```
Name:             project-deployment-5cfb9ccfbd-r7zgj
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             minikube/172.28.249.124
Start Time:       Sun, 04 Feb 2024 17:23:43 -0700
Labels:           app=project-deployment
                  pod-template-hash=5cfb9ccfbd
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.0.113
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.113
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/project-deployment-5cfb9ccfbd
Containers:
  project-pod:
    Container ID:   docker://4d59b3007cd4c14e532510e9c20005b4a11c9ebdd4ccf609719f13befb107824
    Image:          registry/project/app:0.2.3
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://registry.gitlab.com/sdmines/sd/2023/16/project/app@sha256:196c4bf5d6df9feb768cf6276a745ec1dd3077b4fe4150b2c2d8ef6b95193b5b
    Ports:          80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sun, 04 Feb 2024 17:34:51 -0700
      Finished:     Sun, 04 Feb 2024 17:34:51 -0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  7
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-gg5tt (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-gg5tt:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  14m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/project-deployment-5cfb9ccfbd-r7zgj to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     12m (x5 over 14m)     kubelet            Container image "registry/project/app:0.2.3" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    12m (x5 over 14m)     kubelet            Created container project-pod
  Normal   Started    12m (x5 over 14m)     kubelet            Started container project-pod
  Warning  BackOff    4m24s (x48 over 14m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container project-pod in pod project-deployment-5cfb9ccfbd-r7zgj_default(d8dfcdcd-9699-4a58-bb66-108d60167bec)
```

`kubectl logs pod/project-deployment-5cfb9ccfbd-r7zgj`: None 
`kubectl logs pod/project-deployment-5cfb9ccfbd-r7zgj --previous`: None

`kubectl describe deployments/project-deployment`:

```
Name:                   project-deployment
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Sun, 04 Feb 2024 17:23:42 -0700
Labels:                 app=project-deployment
                        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
                        meta.helm.sh/release-name: project
                        meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Selector:               app=project-deployment
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=project-deployment
  Containers:
   project-pod:
    Image:        registry/project/app:0.2.3
    Ports:        80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Host Ports:   0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  Progressing    False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   project-deployment-5cfb9ccfbd (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  16m   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set project-deployment-5cfb9ccfbd to 1
```

I have been installing the app using:
`helm secrets install . project -f enc/secrets.yml`

I declined to include `enc/secrets.yml` in this post because 1. it is entirely secrets and 2. it is encrypted and probably useless in troubleshooting.

Comment: Any luck with running the container outside of Minikube? Just wanting to rule out some issues with your container. Also might wanna check log levels in Production environment e.g. for `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime` are set to at least Information to see if the application is (trying) to start up.

Comment: As far as I can see, the actual project data is not added to publish and hence final is probably empty. Try running the image locally.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, When I run the project via Visual Studio 2022, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was handling my Docker images incorrectly, so when I made a change in VS2022, it wasn't actually changing in my image repo. Thus, my helm chart was pulling outdated images.

For my images, I was using Visual Studio 2022 to build the images and then using `docker image tag` and `docker push` to upload my image to my repo. It appears that this process caused my images to have the same digest, which I believe means that I wasn't ACTUALLY updating anything.
I shouldn't have been using Visual Studio 2022 to build my images. I fixed it by using `docker build -t` and `docker push`.

My app was crashing because of some internal error. Unfortunately, I cannot elaborate on the fix because I made a bunch of changes throughout this process, and I have no clue which change fixed the internal error.